# ggadjustedcurves, fun="cumhaz" does not work

Tags: r, survival

In the 'survminer' package I have been able to construct adjusted curves using cox model but this only shows me the surival function. When I try to input "events" or "cumhaz" into fun= option this only gives me the same survival function. I found this link

https://github.com/kassambara/survminer/issues/287

Wondering if anyone have any suggestions?

I took the advice of Chung30916 in the comment chain and used the following code

`plotdata2<-plotdata%>%
  mutate(cumhaz=1-surv)`

to make a cumulative incidence curve but, forgive me for my inexperience, how do I proceed? Just plot the graph in ggplot2 using the strata (2 groups in my case) and the x will be the time whereas y will be the cumhaz?

Thanks